# Stata infile using .dat file with multiple line obs of varying #s of lines separated by string

Tags: text, stata, infix-notation, file-io

I have large .dat files that I want to import to Stata. The .dat files are two long columns with multiple lines per observation. I want to make variables out of the different lines. The problem is that I cannot use lrecl(#) because the observations are different numbers of lines in length, and there is a string determining when one observation ends and another begins. Here’s what the .dat file looks like (I've separated lines by //):

PATN//
WKU D03321703//
SRC 7//
APN 5583950//
PATN//
WKU D03321711//
SRC 7//
APN 5455359//
APT 4//
ART 294//
APD 19900627//
PATN//
WKU D03321912//
SRC 7//
APN 5455432//
APT 4//
ART 294//
APD 19900456

Each observation begins with “PATN”. I want to tell infile to create variables, say, WKU, SRC, APN and APT using the subsequent columns (as in: infix str WKU 5-13 SRC 5 APN 5-11 APT 5), and then find the next “PATN” to start the next observation. So not only do I need it to find the string “PATN”, I also need it to be able to leave “.” when APN does not exist for that observation.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your description of the data. What does the raw data actually look like? Does it have the // in it, or are those records actually on different lines?

Answer (score 3):

I put your example in a file. Some code follows. To understand more of what it does, sprinkle `list`s liberally.

The philosophy here is simple. Sometimes you can try to do too much within data input. It can be as easy to read in the dataset as undifferentiated text and then manipulate it within Stata. Defining blocks of observations, combining adjacent lines, splitting strings and reshaping the dataset as a whole can all be useful.

```
 
infile str244 text using testtext.dat, clear 
gen long id = sum(text == "PATN")
drop if text == "PATN" 
replace text = text + " " +  text[_n+1] if inlist(text, "APD", "APT", "APN", "ART", "WKU", "SRC")
drop if inlist(word(text[_n-1], 1), "APD", "APT", "APN", "ART", "WKU", "SRC")
split text 
drop text 
rename (text1 text2) (what which) 
reshape wide which, i(id) j(what) string 
renpfix which


. l

     +-------------------------------------------------------+
     | id        APD       APN   APT   ART   SRC         WKU |
     |-------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1              5583950                 7   D03321703 |
  2. |  2   19900627   5455359     4   294     7   D03321711 |
  3. |  3   19900456   5455432     4   294     7   D03321912 |
     +-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Update: This is simpler yet:

```
 
infix str text 1-244 using testtext.dat, clear
gen long id = sum(text == "PATN")
drop if text == "PATN"
split text
rename (text1 text2) (what which)
drop text 
reshape wide which, i(id) j(what) string 
renpfix which 
list
```